# SQL and While from Last to First PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I m need help with SQL and while
The problem is that it lists me from the first to the last so this follows

```
1 - Hello
2 - Hello
3 - Hello
```

but I need this code

```
3 - Hello
2 - Hello
1 - Hello
```

Probably the problem is that I can not use right while
Yes a test is MAX(id) and next ..

Easy code is here

```
$sql = "SELECT id, msg FROM messages ";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
{
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
echo " " . $row["id"]. " - " . $row["msg"]. "</br>";
}
}
```

Comment: Use `order by` and `desc`.

Comment: Unless you specify an `ORDER BY` clause, MySQL can return the rows in any order it wants.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assume that your PHP echo what you need except order of the results. So you have to change only mysql query to this.

`"SELECT id, msg FROM messages ORDER BY id DESC"`

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
$sql = "SELECT id, msg FROM messages ORDER BY id DESC";
```

Answer (score -2):

```
$sql = "SELECT id, msg FROM messages ";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
{
$count = $result->num_rows;
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
echo " " . ($count+1 - $row["id"]). " - " . $row["msg"]. "</br>";
}
}
```

Comment: This won't work if there are gaps in the ID sequence.

Comment: You can also use ($count--) or (--$count)